# I am told to unhide my workbook when I want to delete a macro, but apparently it's already unhidden

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am using Excel 2013 on a macbook air.

When I go to delete a macro I get the following error:

> Cannot edit macro on a hidden workbook. 
>   Unhide the workbook using the unhide command.

I right-click on the worksheet and the "Unhide" command is blank (i.e. it's already unhidden). I then go to the View panel at the top of my screen and there is no clues in how to solve this issue there.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

> I right-click on the worksheet and the "Unhide" command is blank (i.e. it's already unhidden).

What you're doing here would unhide a hidden *worksheet*. To unhide a **workbook**, do the following:

1. In Excel, click the *View* tab, then click **Unhide** in the *Window* group.

   [image: enter link description here]
2. If there is only one hidden workbook, after clicking the Unhide command, the hidden workbook will show up. If there are multiple hidden workbooks, you will find them all listing in the Unhide dialog box after clicking the Unhide button in step 1. Select the workbook and click the **OK** button to display it.

   [image: enter link description here]

[Source](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/523-excel-unhide-workbooks.html)