# Missing the Split, Hide, and Unhide Buttons in Window Pane under View tab on Mac OS

Tags: microsoft-excel

I was trying to follow [this guide](https://superuser.com/questions/1209169/i-am-told-to-unhide-my-workbook-when-i-want-to-delete-a-macro-but-apparently-it) to unhide my personal.xlsb workbook (which I've been able to successfully do on my Laptop that runs Windows), but when I went to the View panel of Excel, I realized I was either missing some buttons/functions in the Window sub-pane, or I was looking in the wrong place for what I'm trying to achieve.

[This is what my View Tab looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RCb5.png)

This is a pretty fresh install, as I just bought a Mac and installed Excel on it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

1. Click on the 'View' menu
2. Right click on the menu ribbon
3. Select 'Customize the Ribbon'
4. Add back the missing buttons

[image]

I hope this solves the problem.